# is there any way to protect questions against edits

Tags: discussion, support

Basically the title sais it all. This is a question I posted today:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/338179/revisions

As you can see the edit butchers the question (removing over half of its content while adding nothing), leaving it in my opinion an incomprehensible mess, or in best case something that can be answered but is useless to us.

We included examples of current theories we got from about 40 guild mates and friends in game (for whom, including myself I post the question). We thought (the 12 ppl that composed, friends who play together) that the theories examples help to better get what we are looking for. Also the note regarding exactly what we expect (official source or user tested data) is very important. All of us run individual tests, but testing alone (we can't correlate data between us because we tested in different ways) is hard in bdo; so we are not looking for some kid posting 2 days of testing, but a real response.

Is not the first time I see this from the same user. We really don't care what the guy considers relevant. He can -1 and move on (that's why the -1 is there).

Edit is there for a reason not deleting more than half a question. Fixing typos, making question clearer, removing any offensive content, etc. NOT turning a question in another one. Is our question, requesting something relevant for us.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to prevent someone from editing a question - collaboration is what we are all about. That said, edits can be rolled back if you feel they fundamentally change the question to something you didn't intend.

That said, the theories are somewhat superfluous - you can't really prove any of them, and they don't really add much to the question. It's great that you have put a lot of thought into what it might be, but you said it yourself - you don't know how true anything is, and you couldn't come up with any real conclusions. So it basically is just adding a lot of muddled data, which doesn't really help to clarify what you actually want to know.

Yes, theoretically, people can down vote and move on, like you said, but in general, we trust our users, especially high rep ones, to have some idea of what works here on the site. You did do the right thing by coming to meta, but do understand that we do work with a spirit of collaboration, so if people think that your question isn't clear or contains stuff that doesn't really help us help you get the answer you want, we are likely to edit it to make it as clear as possible to get you the best answer.

Lastly, please refrain from personal attacks on users like you allude to in your last paragraphs. If you have issues with how something was handled, bring it to meta or flag it for moderator attention - we all want to work together to make things awesome, and this sort of rudeness isn't something we tolerate. I know feelings can get hurt and no one really likes when someone acts without explanation, but trust we are all here with the same good intentions in mind.

Answer (score -3):

First sorry this will be a bit long (and sorry for my not so great english, is not my first language):

Indeed maybe I've gone a bit overboard with last 2 paragraphs and I am sorry if I offended anyone, that was not the intention. I know no1 had bad intentions.

On the other hand pls. understand my point of view. Before posting a question I usually make my own research, corroborate results with friends (if mmo as in this case). This usually takes hours. In this case before posting the question it took weeks (not to mention my over 4500 hours in game). I read/watch over 30 articles/videos etc., took all I got from it, meet with friends and what they found, and posted the question. My hope was to find some NA/Rus/Kor player (I'm on EU) that may have access to other data (especially Kor since I can't read anything in that language). When we decided to put the theories on we also filtered them. The original list had over 10.

Now imagine my frustration when half of that work is deleted without even a comment. Now double it since is not the first time.

Those things are there to avoid answers based on threads like this (this looks like a direct answer but that picture is actually trolling - is edited, not from in game): https://www.reddit.com/r/blackdesertonline/comments/6lqhlj/what_does_investing_energy_to_a_city_do/. Without that note, I could not downvote an answer like this (I would have no basis for it).

Anyway, sorry again if I offended anyone. I consider that whoever edits a question should take in consideration what op needs/wants to know. Basically a bit moderation when moderating because getting an actual usable answer to questions about games that are not "popular" already got extremely hard without removing extra data.

One last note regarding "we trust our users, especially high rep ones". That rep is result of service for community and should be respected. But there are 2 issues with that (that we can't solve but I'm pointing them out anyway). First, you can easily shoot rep up by playing a game like minecraft (is an example) that has thousands of questions and help others with it. Or pokemon go 2 years ago (there were like hundreds of questions/day, with simple answers)? That doesn't make that person a good editor, moderator, etc. Rep sais he is valuable to the community, not in what way.

And second for some users (**and I am NOT pointing fingers, nor speaking about current case**), if you look at the way they behaved (comments, answers etc.) at lets say 20k rep you will notice a little difference between that and how they behave now at 100k+ rep. You will notice that they used to be polite. They used to accept that they may be wrong. Etc.

The SE rep system is the best I've ever seen so far, but pls. understand that is not perfect. I've seen a 15-20 rep user simply crushed by some bigger users and I'm sure that if some of you would want you could do the same to me (just minus everything I post until I get to 0 rep; since I don't play super popular games getting + to compensate would be hard and for an 100k+ loosing 500 rep would be nothing).